# 3 months rolling average for 3 columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Need help

Input

```
Date        A           B       C
2015-10-31  1.49        3.7     7.8
2015-11-30  1.45        3.6     7.6
2015-12-31  1.41        3.7     8.0
2016-01-31  1.33        3.7     8.3
2016-02-29  1.29        4.1     8.6
2016-03-31  1.46        4.4     9.7
```

CREATE TABLE  dbo.ThreeMonth(RDate DATE,A FLOAT,b FLOAT,C FLOAT)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2015-10-31' , 1.49, 3.7,7.8)
INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2015-11-30' , 1.45, 3.6,7.6)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2015-12-31' , 1.41, 3.7,8.0)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2016-01-31' , 1.33, 3.7,8.3)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2016-02-29' , 1.9, 4.1,8.6)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2016-03-31' , 1.46, 4.4,9.7)

INSERT into dbo.threemonth
( RDate , a , b,c)
 VALUES  ( '2016-04-30' , 1.35, 4.3,9.4)

SELECT * FROM threemonth

--Tried the Following query

select rdate,   avg(A)
    OVER (
        ORDER BY Rdate
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
    )
FROM threemonth

OutPut

I need TO display rolling 3 months average FOR 3 COLUMNS a,b,c .WHEN I ADD AVG(b) AND AVG(c) it gives ERROR

"Column 'threemonth.RDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

--Also I want the OUTPUT IN following format

```
 2015-10-31 NULL -- Because 3 months are not available avg cannot be calculated
2015-11-30  NULL -- Because 3 months are not available avg cannot be calculated
2015-12-31  1.45 
2016-01-31  1.39666666666667
2016-02-29  1.54666666666667
2016-03-31  1.56333333333333
2016-04-30  1.57 code here
```

Can somebody advise TO solve the above problem WHERE I need TO TAKE AVG FOR more THEN 1 COLUMN AND display OUTPUT IN the FORMAT I have shown above FOR ALL the 3 COLUMNS?

Answer (score 0):

Somthing Like this

```
;with cteBase as (SELECT *,RowNr = Row_Number() Over (Order by RDate) FROM threemonth )
  Select RDate,Avg=(select Avg(A) from cteBase where RowNr between A.RowNr-2 and A.RowNr and A.RowNr>2)
     From cteBase A
```

Returns

```
RDate       Avg
2015-10-31  NULL
2015-11-30  NULL
2015-12-31  1.45
2016-01-31  1.39666666666667
2016-02-29  1.54666666666667
2016-03-31  1.56333333333333
2016-04-30  1.57
```

For Cols A,B, and C

```
 ;with cteBase as (SELECT *,RowNr = Row_Number() Over (Order by RDate) FROM threemonth )
  Select RDate
        ,AvgA=(select Avg(A) from cteBase where RowNr between A.RowNr-2 and A.RowNr and A.RowNr>2)
        ,AvgB=(select Avg(B) from cteBase where RowNr between A.RowNr-2 and A.RowNr and A.RowNr>2)
        ,AvgC=(select Avg(C) from cteBase where RowNr between A.RowNr-2 and A.RowNr and A.RowNr>2)
     From cteBase A
```

Comment: Thanks . Can you help out if I want to add avg for column b and column c as well.

Comment: Updated my answer to include Col B and A